# How to play videos from a URL into an iphone app with buffering?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an iphone app which requires the videos to be played from the URL.

I dont want to download the whole videos just as it eventually slows down my app.

I want to play the videos in a way that it buffers in between and then plays.

How to play videos from a URL into an iphone app with buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this....

```
NSString *url = @"www.youtube.com/xyz";
NSString *htmlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<object width='212' height='172'><param name='movie' value='%@'></param><param name='wmode' value='transparent'></param><embed src='%@'type='application/x-shockwave-flash' wmode='transparent' width='980' height='965'></embed></object>",url,url];

[myWebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Are you sure this would run the video with buffering?

Comment: This doesnt work for me. It just shows a blank screen in webView. Nothing is shown up.

Comment: @ParthBhatt May be this is too late to answer. But FYI,this will only work in Device as iPhone simulator doesn't support flash.

Comment: what if I do not want to use uiwebview?

Answer (score 0):

do you have own server for streaming?

then,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://STREAMING URL"];
[myMPMoviePlayerController setContentURL: url];
[myMPMoviePlayerController play];
```