# How to Play Youtube Link Videos in My App?

Tags: iphone, youtube, video-streaming

I want to play YouTube video in my Application. I written the code below but the video cant played please tell me how to play the video, Thanks in Advance

```
NSURL *url =[NSUrl UrlWithString: @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MSMJgpmVM8&feature=grec_index"];;
    NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head>\
<body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";    
videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 320.0, 412.0)];

[videoView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,url, videoView.frame.size.width, videoView.frame.size.height];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:videoView];
```

Comment: This paste is incorrect. `*url` doesn't have a value. and the call to `stringWithFormat` is wrong.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013614/how-to-play-videos-from-a-url-into-an-iphone-app-with-buffering

Comment: same problem, please tell me how to play?

Answer (score 0):

hey i dont think you will need to embed anything.you can simply shoot the webView with the appropriate URL...i had done dis a week back...it played the videos in Youtube..
Cheerzz..!!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026942/how-to-play-local-and-server-url-video-in-iphone/6026963#6026963) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015165/playing-a-video-file-from-server-in-an-iphone-app)

Just Pass your URL in fileURL

Comment: I am used this link but it doesnt played

Comment: However You r doing something wrong otherwise this is the best solution...Can you post the code?

Comment: Mehul, did you try similar code, can u post the working code?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to get the HTML to place in a `UIWebView`

```
- (NSString *)YouTubeHTMLForURL:(NSString *)URLString;
{
  int w = streamWebView.frame.size.width;
  int h = streamWebView.frame.size.height;

    NSString *HTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    width:%dpx;\
    height:%dpx;\
    background-color:#252525;\
    color:white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:HTML, w, h, URLString, w, h];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWebView  *wbView = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,url, 64.0, 64.0];
    [wbView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

  "url" is your video url

@Mike video plays only on device not on simulator
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code should work -

But Please note that youtube only works in device are you checking this on device.

```
UIWebView  *wbView = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,url, 64.0, 64.0];
    [wbView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```